# Bandwidth control on Davolink DV-2020

Tags: openwrt

I'd like to ensure enough Internet bandwidth to a specific PC at home so that I can still talk over Skype when my daughter is watching films online but any bandwidth control is not available in the current (supplied by Tele2 in Holland) firmware of Davolink DV-2020 - does anyone have any experience with installing OpenWrt on DV-2020 ( http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/davolink/dv-2020?s[]=davolink ) ? Does OpenWrt enable any bandwidth control at all ?

Thanks,
Artur

Answer (score 1):

There is bandwidth control on openwrt. However it mainly controls upload and "can" prioritize download UDP packets. 
Also from the link you gave, there is no supported openwrt version for your router.

Comment: There's some info on OpenWrt installation on DV-2020 on http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/davolink/dv-2020?s[]=davolink but I just don't know how to stop at CFE during power reboot to upload a build image...